# Movie API, passing data through?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm currently learning React and wanted to do a movie website project with a ticket system.

I want it so that when I click the ticket icon it will redirect me to a ticket page. However, I don't know how to link the movie details to that button press so that when it leads me there it can have the selected movie image and details show up and linked to the purchase ticket function.

movie.jsx:

```
<p onClick={ticketpage}>
          <FaTicket />
        </p>

 const ticketpage = async () => {
      navigate('/purchaseticket')
    }
```

purchaseticket.jsx:

```
return (
    <div className=''>
        <div className=''>
        <img className='w-full aspect-auto'
    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${item?.backdrop_path}`} alt={item?.title}   
        />
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more info/code snippet?

Comment: @VasuKuncham Hey Vasu, 
Here's a link to the full project, my main focus is just trying to figure out how to get the movie information to push through to the purchase ticket/page. I've attempted by myself before coming here but I'm stumped.  https://github.com/bamb1zzle/tongariro